# 1000+ API calls with 1 cron job?

Tags: php, mysql, api, curl, cron

we have the following potential situation:

A web app that could have 1000+ Users.

We want to setup a cronjob to fetch data via an external-service API for ALL 1000+ users with one cronjob call (NOTE: each user has their own API credentials with that external API service)!

What would be a sensible way to do it?

Info:

- One API call with credentials could take up to 5(!) seconds to get data back.

Possible script:

Cronjob calls a local php script (cronjobcall.php), that loops through all 1000 users. For each user this script calls another local script via curl (localfile_calls_api.php) that makes the actual API call and saves the returned data into MySQL database.

cronjobcall.php

```
foreach($ThousandsOfUsers as $UserId => $UserCredentials)
{

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "localfile_calls_api.php?UserId=$UserId&UserCredentials=$UserCredentials");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result=curl_exec($ch);

}
```

localfile_calls_api.php

```
// !!! this could take up to 5(!) seconds to return result

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://external_api_url.php?UserId=$UserId&UserCredentials=$UserCredentials");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result=curl_exec($ch);

if($result)
{
save_to_MySql($result,$UserId);
}
```

So, that's why I think of splitting the whole procedure into two different php files, because the API call itself could take up to 5 seconds to return data.

Is this the right approach?

Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: 5 seconds? Why does that matter? Why do you thinking putting the API call in a separate PHP file would make *any* difference? You're looking at a whopping 5000 seconds for all users, hardly worth thinking twice about. Just put everything in a single PHP file and it will work *no differently* than putting them in two files; there's no reason at all to think two files is somehow better/faster.

Comment: Why do you need the data refreshed periodically? If you just need it for the user, just make the api call when the user logs in.

Comment: I was thinking that would have been better...but what do I do with 5000 seconds? That's ca. 83 minutes! How can a server do this? Most servers have setup to stop a page load after 30-40 seconds...? Is there a better way to do it, than looping like this?

Comment: Data needs to be updated periodically via API, since data changes periodically for each user of that external service. Think of it like "Twitter" API etc... Each Twitter user has different data that can be fetched via API with their own API credentials.

Comment: @user1033406 "Most servers have setup to stop a page load after 30-40 seconds...?" You are mistaken over what "page load" means. There is no time-out for PHP scripts executed from cron jobs. There is no "page load" and no request, and nothing to time out. The script will just run until its done. 5000 seconds or 5000 hours, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Good to know. I haven't used Cron Jobs before much, so had a different idea about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to make that API call for each user periodically, I would set it up differently:

- Add two columns to your table: `lastUpdated` and `isBeingProcessed` (or something similar);
- Make a script that runs every X (1?) minutes using cron;
- In your script, get the XX (10?) records with the oldest `lastUpdated` date and that not being processed and set the `isBeingProcessed` flag;
- As each API call finishes, update the user information including the `lastUpdated` date or time an unset the `isBeingProcessed` flag;

Depending on what your server can handle and what the API allows, you can even set it up to have multiple jobs run simultaneously / overlapping, reducing the total time to update a lot.