# PHP execute in Background won´t work good without delay

Tags: php, asynchronous, exec, simultaneous

I need to ping a few servers every 5 minutes and this takes more than 30 sec overall. So I thought I use the exec command to do this in background:

```
function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } 
    else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
} 

$result  = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `servers` ORDER BY `id`");

while ($server_data = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    sleep(1);
    execInBackground("php server_updater.php " . $server_data['id']);

}
```

As you see I added a sleep of one second. Which I don´t want and doesn´t work as I have to check more than 30 servers. Well if I don´t set the 1 sec sleep, the update script fails for a few servers which are online:

The update script gets the id of the server which it should update from the script from above and than runs a query to check the servers status. If it succeeds it enters the data into the database if it fails it updates the server entry in the database to offline.

According to mysql_query, this only works with internal data, no possibility for the user to modify anything.

What do you think, why do some of the server checks fail if there is no sleep. Which optimazations or better ways could you recommend ?

Comment: the only thing thin the foreground should be a single call to the start the background process which would include the db query and loop

Comment: Perhaps your (shared?) server runs out of resources (memory, number of processes, etc.) when you try to execute all 30+ scripts at the same time. I would use something like a queue and a scheduler (cron in Linux) instead, see for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661370/1000-api-calls-with-1-cron-job/21661938#21661938

Comment: @Dagon sorry I did not understand what you said.

Comment: @jeroen thats a good idea, I already set a timestamp to display the last update on the page and use cron to execute the script. Does it work if I execute the script with multiple crons at the same time or do I have to use a wrapper script with exec the update script multiple times in background ?

Comment: You can't do it all at the same time as you'll have the same problem as now. I would do batches in different cron jobs.

Comment: @jeroen what I mean is, that it works perfect to update 10-20 servers at the same time on the vserver and even 50 in my local environment. So to speed it up I could run the script 5 times simultaneously. but if I execute the update directly without a wrapper script with ´exec´ does this block the rest ?

Comment: If you are already doing multiple simultaneous cronjobs, there is no need anymore to use a wrapper script to do more simultaneous jobs, then you really loose track of what is happening. You could look into table locking to make sure that every script executing gets a unique set of jobs to execute.

Comment: @jeroen what I meant is, if I execute the update myself via a browser without the exec. I have to wait until it is finished to access any page. So if I execute the script directly without another one running it in background, would it slowdown/pause the rest ?

Comment: No, you would not notice anything unless the server is hitting its limits. Is your script using sessions? That would explain potential blocking behaviour in the browser.

Comment: the script it self not. but I import it via another import. I should change that.

Comment: @jeroen you should put the comments into an answer that I can accept it ;)

Comment: Hahaha, it's really just a link to another answer and a discussion that got out of hand. Feel free to upvote my other answer though if you find it useful :-)

Comment: @jeroen its more about other people finding this question and reading the answers but not the comments ;)

Comment: Good point, answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your (shared?) server runs out of resources (memory, number of processes, etc.) when you try to execute all 30+ scripts at the same time.

I would use something like a queue and a scheduler (cron in Linux) instead, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661370/1000-api-calls-with-1-cron-job/21661938#21661938). In summary you "check out" a batch of records to be updated and process them sequentially.

It would depend on the resources you have at your disposal, but you could run multiple jobs at the same time, each processing a part of your queue one after another (no need for async `exec()` calls).

You should also look into table locking to make sure no records get "checked out" by multiple versions of your script.

Answer (score 0):

While not answering the backgrounding problem, this answer might be helpful anyway:

For **storing time series data**, [RRDtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) ist a great solution. It saves large amounts of data over time and convert this data into suchlike **charts**:

[image]

Additionally, I'd propose to use a **specialist monitoring solution**. One solution with a good visual presentation of system states ist [CACTI](http://www.cacti.net). From the [CACTI website](http://www.cacti.net/image.php?image_id=29):

[image]

Comment: thanks, but thats not exactly what I need. I already use monitorix for this ;)